# css selectors get parent based on child

Tags: css, css-selectors

How do I do something like "Select all elements, whose child match a certain selector"?

For example. There are some elements `<div>`, each of these elements has a `<a>` child, some of these are `<a class="typ1">`, and some of these are `<a class="typ2">`. I want to select all `<div>` elements, that have an `<a>` child with a `typ1` class.

I know that if I want to `<a>` elements I can do something like `a.typ1', but how do I get the`` parent?

Comment: That's often called a parent selector, and it doesn't exist in CSS. You have to do this with JS instead, or find another solution. There will be a _sort of_ parent selector in CSS soon, but it seems even that will only work via JS. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

As of now, there is **NO WAY** to refer back to parent in CSS. Please refer to this
[**W3 documentation.**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/)

Comment: Bolding the entire text is as good as not bolding anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is **no way** to select parent using css. but you can use jquery to do this.

see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/nobot7cn/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a class="type-1">as</a>
</div>
<div>
    <a class="type-2">asd</a>    
</div>
<div>
       <a class="type-3">asd</a>    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.type-1-parent{
    background:red;

}
.type-2-parent{
    background:blue;

}
.type-3-parent{
    background:green;

}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".type-1").parent("Div").addClass("type-1-parent");
//or use closest method
//$(".type-1").closest("Div").addClass("type-1-parent");
$(".type-1").parent("Div").addClass("type-1-parent");
$(".type-2").parent("Div").addClass("type-2-parent");
$(".type-3").parent("Div").addClass("type-3-parent");
```

*I hope this is what you want*

Comment: Why go straight to a jQuery "solution" when the original question gives no indication that jQuery is being used. Proper JavaScript should be supplied instead.

Comment: @Shaggy Why use JavaScript if Jquery has more flexibility, extensibity and support

Comment: The original comment did not mention jQuery or Javascript.

Comment: The OP asked about css, since there is no possible solution with css for the requirement I suggested a solution using jquery

Comment: @droidev JQuery would add thousands of lines for this simple task